# Wrong shared folder permissions on virtualbox guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox, shared-folders

I have a centos guest and I have enabled shared folders. The shared folder is mounted at `/media/sf_vbox` (witch is annoying as I named the folder `vbox` on the host).

```
[duser@centos01 ~]$ ls -l /media
total 2
drwxrwx---. 1 root vboxsf 2048 Feb 22 17:50 sf_vbox
[duser@centos ~]$
```

The problem is that I can't access it as a normal user and neither `chmod` or `chown` works, the ownership and permissions stays the same.

Note that `/media/sf_vbox` is perfectly accessible as root.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was rather simple as it turned out, append the user who needs access to the group `vboxsf` and reboot for the permission to take effect.

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf duser
```